# How to find units of rings?

Tags: ring-theory, soft-question

In ring theory, I've been learning about units of rings, and although I'm able to understand the concept and write proofs involving it, I have a lot of struggle actually finding the units of specific rings.

Say, for example, the ring $\mathbb Z[i\sqrt 5]$, How can I find the units of this ring?

Is there any standard approach to solve this kind of problem or does it always depend on the ring we're working with? Any tips for approaching this kinds of question?

Comment: Minor nitpick: "Unity" usually refers to the element $1$, while "unit" refers to invertible elements. I admit that this is a little inconvenient.

Comment: But the plural is still unities? @Arthur

Comment: The plural of "unit" is "units". "Unity" has plural "unities" (although given what it means in abstract algebra, you don't usually see that one pluralised).

Comment: Thank you @Arthur

Comment: In $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ the units are just $\pm 1.$ That’s because, for $x\in \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}],$ $|x|>1$ unless $x\in\{\pm1,0\}.$ So if $xy=1,$ then $|x|\cdot |y|=1$ which means $x,y=\pm 1.$

Comment: In general, when your ring is the algebraic integers of a number field which has a “norm” $N:R\to\mathbb Z,$ the units will always be the elements $r\in R$ with $N(r)=\pm1.$ There can be infinitely many, as there are in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt2].$

Comment: I don't think I get that:/ What would that "norm" be in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$ for example? @ThomasAndrews

Comment: $N(a+b\sqrt{2})=a^2-2b^2.$ In general, for the ring $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{D}],$ the norm is $$N(a+b\sqrt D)=a^2-Db^2=(a+b\sqrt{D})(a-b\sqrt D).$$ The formula gets more complicated for roots of polynomials of higher degree than $2.$ The norm has the property that $N(xy)=N(x)N(y)$ and the norm $N(x)=0\iff x=0.$

Comment: Thank you @ThomasAndrews

Comment: The only units of each non-real quadratic field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{- d})$ where $d\ne 1,3$ are $1$ and $-1$, like as in $\mathbb Z$.